# using C# to make an algorithm to understand 00/00/00

Tags: c#

I am writing C# code for a business rule in a program called Prophet 21.

The code essentially is saying, if a product price has been updated in the last year, put that price into a field called PO Price.

Everything works solid except for one tiny problem, when making sure that the price was updated within the last year, it looks at the PO Price update date.  At some point in the past, a lot of these were set to 00/00/00 and using an algorithm with date doesn't seem to understand it.  My best guess is that I need to convert the date somehow, but I am quite a C# novice, any help would be appreciated.  Here's the code I am working with.

```
public class SetPOCost : Rule  //this rule sets the PO cost to the other cost when the item is stockable and the disposition is B
{
    public override RuleResult Execute()
    {
        RuleResult result = new RuleResult();

        result.Success = true;

        string s = Data.Fields["other_cost"].FieldValue;
        decimal ldcOtherCost = Convert.ToDecimal(s);
        s = Data.Fields["po_cost"].FieldValue;
        decimal ldcPOCost = Convert.ToDecimal(s);
        string stockable = Data.Fields["stockable"].FieldValue;
        string disposition = Data.Fields["disposition"].FieldValue;
        s = Data.Fields["ufc_inventory_supplier_date_cost_last_modified"].FieldValue;
        //this next line is added from the SuggestPromiseDate rule because it was running into errors doing both rules
        Data.Fields.GetFieldByAlias("suggested_promise_date").FieldValue = Data.Fields.GetFieldByAlias("line_max_promise_date").FieldValue;
        DateTime dtLastModified = Convert.ToDateTime(s);

        DateTime thisDate = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime thisDateLastYear = thisDate.AddYears(-1);
        Boolean dateIsGood = dtLastModified.CompareTo(thisDateLastYear) >= 0;

        if (stockable == "N" && disposition == "B" && ldcPOCost == 0 && ldcOtherCost > 0 && dateIsGood)
        {
            Data.Fields["po_cost"].FieldValue = ldcOtherCost.ToString();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Programmers forever come up with crazy "not a real value" literals.  Certainly inspired by the very drastic mistake of storing dates into a table column type of string.  Nothing you couldn't fix by simply comparing the string, that wheel keeps on spinning and keeps programmers in clothes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TryParse to check the date coming in.

```
s = Data.Fields["ufc_inventory_supplier_date_cost_last_modified"].FieldValue;
//this next line is added from the SuggestPromiseDate rule because it was running into errors doing both rules
Data.Fields.GetFieldByAlias("suggested_promise_date").FieldValue = Data.Fields.GetFieldByAlias("line_max_promise_date").FieldValue;

DateTime dtLastModified;
if (DateTime.TryParse(s, out dtLastModified) == false)
    dtLastModified = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Comment: Note `if(!DateTime.TryParse(s, out dtLastModified))` is a very common idiom, albeit harder to understand if you're not used to it.

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

```
s = Data.Fields["ufc_inventory_supplier_date_cost_last_modified"].FieldValue;
if (s == "00/00/00") {
    s="01/01/0001";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`00/00/00` is not a valid date in .NET; dates start counting from January 1st, 0001.  Detect when this date occurs in your original data source, and then create a new date as `new DateTime(0);`.

Comment: great suggestion, that was my first original fix for this issue, but I am being told that I am not going to be allowed to change anything in our SQL database.